# JVM intermitent chrashes on garbage collection

Tags: crash, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot, jvm-crash

We have an JSF app deployed on jboss5 with JVM HotSpot build 1.6.0_14-b08. On a machine with 4 cores.

In the last few days we encountered a few sudden crashes of the JVM accodring to the fatal error log it looks like taht it is caused during garbage collection calls.

we use this flags in JVM to determin GC 
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"

How can we track the root cause? I'm not an expert in examin the fatal error logs.

Some of the causes :

1.)

```
 ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000004d8dc800):  VMThread [stack:0x0000000040d83000,0x0000000040e84000] [id=24601]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=2 (SEGV_ACCERR), si_addr=0x00002aaaae1ff000

......

VM_Operation (0x000000005ea08b40): ParallelGCFailedAllocation, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x0000000051def000
```

2.)

```
 ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

 Current thread (0x0000000041ec8800):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000] [id=19822]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=2 (SEGV_ACCERR), si_addr=0x00002aaaae1ff008
```